# Writing a named building/place

Tags: grammar, particle-の

Does one write:

Smith toshokan
or
Toshokan no Smith

Apologies for not using kana, the Windows' Japanese keyboard is taking forever to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I lived in Japan, all the libraries I came across were Name+Library. For instance, 京都府立図書館 or "Kyoto Prefecture Library."

"no" indicates possession. Toshokan no Smith would mean "The Library's Smith." Smith no toshokan would be awkward (and I think incorrect, at least based on my experience) but would mean Smith's Library, which at least makes sense.